# Quantas casas decimais do CSS o Browser aceita ou reconhece?

Tags: css3, navegador-de-internet

Tenho visto cada vez mais valores com múltiplas casas decimais nos estilos do CSS. Então surgiu a dúvida. Até quantas casas decimais de fato o CSS aceita e o Browser consegue renderizar?

Valores como esses funcionam de forma precisa?

```
width: 8.33333333%; (Grid do Bootstrap por exemplo)
```

ou

```
font-size: 1.062575rem; (conversões de PX em REM)
```

Essas casas decimais realmente são interpretadas precisamente pelo Browser, ou tanto ele quanto o CSS tem um limite de casas decimais?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cada navegador trabalha de uma maneira diferentes com pontos flutuantes.
Para garantir que funcione corretamente, você pode trabalhar com frações e calc.

Por exemplo:

```
width: calc(100% / 3);
```

Fonte: https://www.sitepoint.com/a-tale-of-css-and-sass-precision/

Answer (score 0):

Parece que nem o CSS quanto o HTML tem uma limitação de casas decimais. Esse calculo vai ficar por conta de Browser, e de acordo com essa tabela de para ver claramente que os Browser modernos trabalham muito melhor com essas casas decimais e cálculos mais complexos.

```
Internet Explorer 7 truncate to 2 decimal places
Internet Explorer 8 truncate to 2 decimal places
Internet Explorer 9 truncate to 2 decimal places
Internet Explorer 10    truncate to 2 decimal places
Internet Explorer 11    truncate to 2 decimal places
Firefox 3.0 truncate to 3 decimal places
Firefox 3.5 truncate to 3 decimal places
Firefox 31  truncate to 3 decimal places
Chrome 20   round to 15 decimal places
Chrome 21   round to 15 decimal places
Chrome 37   round to 13 decimal places
Safari 6 (OSX Lion) round to 15 decimal places
Safari 6.1 (OSX Mountain Lion)  round to 15 decimal places
Safari 7 (OSX Mavericks)    round to 15 decimal places
Mobile Safari 7 (iOS7)  round to 15 decimal places
Mobile Safari 8 (iOS8)  round to 15 decimal places
Chrome 36 (Jelly Bean) [Nexus5] round to 15 decimal places
Chrome 30 (KitKat) [S5] round to 15 decimal places
Android Browser 4 (Jelly Bean) [Nexus7,Nexus4,S4,S3]    round to 15 decimal places
Android Browser 4 (Ice Cream Sandwich) [Nexus,KindleFire2]  round to 15 decimal places
Android Browser 4 (Gingerbread) [S2]    truncate to 3 decimal places
Opera 12    truncate to 2 decimal places
Opera Next 24   round to 13 decimal places
```

**Fonte:** http://cruft.io/posts/percentage-calculations-in-ie/

*Para quem tiver curiosidade e quiser testar o browser para ver quantas casas ele reconhece aqui tem uma página de teste.* http://cruft.io/static/rounding/